# "Save As" Command Button in MS Word 2016?

Tags: microsoft-word, toolbar, microsoft-word-2016, save-as, ribbon

I can't find any way to **add a "Save As" command button** to my Ribbon or Quick Access Toolbar.

- When I search through "All Commands" in the customization menu, there doesn't seem to be any "Save As" command.

I know that there is a "Save As" option under the File tab, but I'd like to have a "Save As" button available for my quick access toolbar.

Word 2016 seems to have maintained the save button, so why not the "Save As" button?

So...

1. **If the "Save As" command button *exists*, how do I add it to my Ribbon or Quick Access toolbar?**
2. **If the "Save As" command button *doesn't* exist, how could I add/create one?**

---

Here is a screenshot of Word 2016 (Windows 7) showing the "Save" button but lack of "Save As" button.

[image]

Comment: "Save As" is, as it currently seems, too complicated. I have to go through File > Save As > Browse, when previously a single click on a "Save As" button did the same thing... -_-

Answer (score 1):

While this isn't a solution to your question, pressing F12 will open up the SaveAs dialog box.

You can also save this macro to your Normal document, then assign the macro to a button that goes on your toolbar.

```
Sub saveAs()
    Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs).Show 
End Sub
```

When I renamed my macro then re-added it to the toolbar, it seems to work every time from the button.

Comment: Thanks. I actually never use that. +1. Still, like you said, not quite a *solution* but more of a workaround...So I ask that others still answer the question more directly if possible.

Comment: Your welcome. I have posted an actual solution.

Comment: Thanks, @wizlog. But after creating the macro and saving it to a button, nothing happens when I click on it. Works fine in VBA editor though. Strange...

Comment: Actually, it appears that after making the macro into a button, when I click on it, it just saves the document as "Doc1" behind the scenes. Subsequent clicks on the macro button simply performs the same save action as the "Save" button (i.e., it doesn't open a dialog box)

Comment: Does the same happen to you?

Comment: For me, it opens the window.  What if you just press F5 while within the macro?

Comment: F5 works as expected when stepped into macro. But once I create a ribbon (or quick access toolbar) button for the macro, it doesn't work as it does in vba editor.

Comment: Very strange, I'll look into that a little later.

Comment: I've opened up a [new question](https://superuser.com/q/1229649/647254) to address this strange change in macro behavior once it's assigned to a button.

Comment: Okay, then is my answer correct? or only after I append the resolution from that question?

Comment: @theforestecologist updated my answer to reflect changes I made that worked for me.

Comment: I'm confused -- your edit history doesn't show that you made any changes...? Your answer still doesn't work for me as a button :/. I've now updated Word to 16.0.8229.2086 with the same non-working results.

Comment: When I renamed my macro then re-added it to the toolbar, it seems to work every time from the button.