# Macro changes functionality when assigned as button in Word 2016

Tags: microsoft-word, macros, microsoft-word-2016, save-as, ribbon

When I create a SaveAs macro in Word 2016, it functions differently when I assign it to a command button on the ribbon (or on the quick access toolbar).

**Macro:**

```
Sub saveAs()
    Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs).Show 
End Sub
```

**Expected/desired effect:**

- Open up a Save As dialog box.

**What it *actually* does:**

- **In VBA editor**: it runs as expected and opens the SaveAs window.

  - This is true whether I hit run or use F5 (the run shortcut).
- **In Macro List** (i.e., after selecting "View Macros"): again, runs as expected after clicking the "Run" button.
- **As Macro command Button**: does *not* perform desired action

  - If file was previously unsaved, the macro button saves the file as "Doc1.docx" without ever opening a SaveAs dialog box.
  - If file has previously been saved, the button simply acts as a Save button and saves the current state to the existing file (again, without opening the dialog box).

#### My question:

**Why does this happen and what can I do to make it work as expected?**

---

Specs:
Word 2016 MSO (16.0.8229.2073) 32-bit on a Windows 7 machine

Note: This post is in response to an issue I'm having with a solution to this [question](https://superuser.com/q/1229619/647254).

---

Update:

I experience the same effect when I use `Dialogs(wdDialogFileSaveAs).Show` or even `Dialogs(wdDialogFilePrint).Show.`

- Again, in both cases, the desired effect occurs in VBA editor but a button assigned to the macro acts differently (and undesirably).

Update2:

I experience the same lack of functionality after updating to the [currently] most recent version: 16.0.8229.2086

Comment: Note: I have a dozen other macros that *work as expected* when assigned as a Ribbon button. (Ex. `Selection.Find` macros and `Selection.InsertSymbol` macros).  So it might have something to do with the type of action I'm trying to perform???

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem posted in your other question by simply renaming the macro, ensuring it's in the Normal document, and reassigning a button to it.

Hope this helps.